# @font-face Font Weight changes as page loads (weight set to normal)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

We are using Interval Sans with @font-face. Each font element has font-weight:normal applied to it. There are no strong fields associated with the elements.

http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/mostardesign/interval

On several text elements, when the page first loads we see the correct and slender font rendering. After a moment the fonts "gain weight" artificially, which takes away the nice effect of the custom font.

Here is a 30 second video showing it happen:
http://www.screencast.com/t/vGN6zLbKh

I have googled extensively and almost all the results relate to adding artificial font weights to custom fonts that do not have a full suite of font weights. We are at a loss for our issue.

The font weight issues can be seen in Mac Chrome, but they are instantly faux-bold in Mac Firefox and Safari. Our development team says they cannot reproduce the flicker/change in Windows browsers.

I appreciate any insight!

Comment: Hard to answer this question without a URL. Do you have something you can show us live? Am guessing this is a CSS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to be using [FlexSlider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider) on the site?

I was having the exact same issue with the font weight seeming to flash/flicker and wasn't using `@font-face`.

After spending some time debugging, I found the `slideshowSpeed` variable in the Flexslider script was causing the issue. I removed the custom setting for that variable and the flashing text went away.

Even if you aren't using FlexSlider, I'd suggest checking out if some bit of javascript is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like kerning. without seeing the code, pretty hard to pin it down exactly. are you using optimizeLegibility in your css? did you generate a kit for cross-browser compatibility?